# Multi tenant EF implementation w/ Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

When using SProcs in EF4, I understand the concept of mapping views to entities, then using function imports to map my set/update/deletes to sprocs. The question I have is how this applies to multi tenant architecture. Consider the following scenario:

We have several hundred customers utilizing our multi-tenant database/application. Each customer has somewhere between 50-200 Accounts in the Accounts table. If I expose a view to EF, I cannot parameterize that view. So the following line:

```
query = (from e in context.Accounts select e).where(e => e.companyID = 1)
[forgive me if I'm syntactically incorrect. still learning EF!]
```

,by definition, would have to return all of the Accounts first, then filter using my wear clause. is this correct? I can't imagine how else the process would work.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, you do have a bad design.

Comment: @John: care to illuminate us on which part is a bad design?  Multi-tenant architectures of the type the OP is talking about are pretty common.

Comment: I consider it a bad design to put all the tenant's data into a single database. Doing so requires that the "tenant id" be part of every primary key, for instance, otherwise you're open to absurdities like a customer of one tenant ordering the products of another.

Comment: (a) I didn't design it, have any say in the design, or have the ability to change the design. (b) Multi-tenant design are common (c) Thank you for such illumination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF shouldn't be bringing all the accounts back first and then filtering. Rather, it should be be emitting a query with a WHERE clause.

You can check using SQL Profiler, just to be 100% sure.

Comment: Okay, I'll double check tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is the difference between Linq-To-Objects and Linq-To-Entities. Linq-To-Objects operates on `IEnumerable<T>` and you pass delegates to its methods to define the query which will be executed in the memory. Linq-To-Entities operates on `IQueryable<T>` and you pass expressions to its methods do define expression tree which is transformed by Linq-to-entities provider into another syntax - to SQL!

So your query will be executed in the database and filtering will be done in the database as well. Be aware that after executing commands like `AsEnumerable`, `ToArray`, `ToDictionary` or `ToList` you transform the rest of the query to Linq-to-objects.

If you write the query on the result of stored procedure execution you are always doing Linq-to-objects only querying ObjectSets directly forms Linq-to-entities queries.